# Windows 10 disk partitions' meaning

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

This is the image of all the disk partitions on my windows machine. I want to know what each of these partitions mean (except `C: OS`, `D: Music` and `E: Disciple`). I also want to know what effect it would have if I were to delete any of these partitions. (I want to free up some space to be able to dual boot with ubuntu)

More importantly, what problems will I face if I delete the last `Image` partition that is using up 10gb of my hdd.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First partition (EFI) is the BIOS partition.

Second through Fifth except 3rd: Yours.

Third:  May occur from the original setup

Sixth and Seventh:  Partitions to be able to rebuild to factory specifications .

These are all normal partitions in Windows 10

Comment: I did not do those partitions. What happens if I delete the bios partition? What happens if I delete the WINRETOOLS partition? What happens if I delete the 10GB Image partition?

Comment: If you delete the EFI BIOS partition, your computer won't start. Don't delete this.  If you delete the other partitions, you will not be able to rebuild to factory specs if you need to. I suggest not deleting these. Windows 10 builds these partitions (you do not need to)

Comment: 3rd is the factory boot partition, 7th is where the factory image is stored, 6th is where the winre (Windows recovery environment) recovery tools are, which is for repair rather than recovering the factory image.